# CrystalReports .NET rellenar campos texto objeto OLE desde codigo c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

Tengo diseñado un report con campos de texto de tipo Objeto OLE y quiero rellenar estos campos desde código C#. Pero no se como hacerlo.

Normalmente hacia una consulta SQL en el report y sus campos los arrastraba al report para luego desde C# vincular los datos a una tabla.

Pero lo que quiero hacer es la consulta SQL desde C# y rellenar los objetos OLE con los datos de mi consulta.

Comment: Has intentado usar `FormulaFields` o parámetros para asignar esos datos a los campos de Texto? , Esta pregunta puede ser un poco amplia, ya que para asignar esos datos, tienes que configurar los parámetros de conexión vía código al momento de cargar el reporte y controlar otras cosas.... Si colocas lo que llevas realizado hasta el momento, es más fácil partir desde ahí para ayudarte.

Comment: Como explicaba me funciona si los campos Objecto OLE los sustituyo por  "Campos de base de datos - comando" porque previamente hago una consulta para crear esos campos - comando. Pero no se como hacerlo para directamente rellenar los Objeto OLE sin hacer consulta en el report, sino desde c#

Comment: Intentare poner lo que estoy haciendo pero es que no tiene código. simplemente creo un report con una pagina y a ese pagina le pongo unos campos de tipo Objeto OLE luego en C# quiero rellenar esos campos dinámicamente.